# what is wrong in this reaction?

Tags: siunitx, mhchem

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{isotope}
\begin{document}
\section{Decay mode of  \ce{Be isotope}}

$\ce{^4_2Be -> [5x10^3}{ns}][{1.37 MeV}] ^4_2He + 2p^+}$\\
\end{document}
```

I read a error that a $ is missing or plus.

any solution?

Comment: What output would you expect? Currently, there seems to be a mismatch between `{` and `}`.

Comment: Correct suggestion of the user *leandriis*. This MWE works correctly: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{isotope}
\begin{document}
\section{Decay mode of \ce{Be isotope}}

$\ce{^4_2Be -> [\num{5e3} {ns}][{1.37 MeV}] ^4_2He + 2p^+}$
\end{document}`. For `siunitx` package I have read to page 4: `\num{5e3}`.

Answer (score 6):

The one apparent error is a missing opening brace in `[5x10^3}{ns}]`. But there are other things:

- `5x10^3}{ns}` should be `\SI{5e3}{ns}` or `\SI{5e3}{\nano\second}` or at least `$5\times10^3\,\mathrm{ns}$`
- `{1.37 MeV}` should be `\SI{1.37}{MeV}` or `\SI{1.37}{\mega\electronvolt}` or at least `$1.37\,\mathrm{MeV}$`
- `\ce{Be isotope}` should be `\ce{Be} isotope`
- `-> [` should be `->[` (the blank is wrong there)
- the math mode around `$\ce{...}$` isn't necessary
- `\\` at the end of the line is wrong

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\section{Decay mode of  \ce{Be} isotope}

\ce{^4_2Be ->[\SI{5e3}{\nano\second}][\SI{1.37}{\mega\electronvolt}] ^4_2He + 2p^+}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: sorry to ask again: and antiparticle like anti-neutino? i can use heparticle? and yes, your version work very good. thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

Possibly "\SI{" is missing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{isotope}
\begin{document}
\section{Decay mode of  \ce{Be isotope}}

$\ce{^4_2Be ->[ \SI{5e3}{ns}][{1.37 MeV}] ^4_2He + 2p^+}$\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ops :-) excuse me. You have beat me for 5 sec. :-) I delete my answer and put a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `hepparticles` package, you have either to use its syntax, e.g. `\HepParticle{p}{}{+}` for a proton, or write a shortcut such as

```
\newcommand{\Pproton}{\HepParticle{p}{}{+}}
```

in your preamble in order to use it elsewhere in your document. That was not the case from your screenshot (and please take the time to write code in your question).

A few more thing :

- as `mhchem` does not need to be enclosed in a math environment, you can ditch the `$`, it will make your code lighter;
- the way you write it, it might take less effort to stick with `mhchem`;
- also, should it not be beryllium-6 that undergoes that decay ?

Comment: I use this only to see if it work, is not offical work. it still not working. I try many things I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I had forgotten a \ for the \HepParticle. Corrected, it works fine for me.